# Why django is not accepting spaces in template?

Tags: django

`{%  %}` means that this is a django template delimiter. So inside `{%  %}` the space should not matter I guess.
Now in the example:

```
<a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
```

This is showing expected output whereas

```
<a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk = post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
```

is showing error.
Why this is sensitive to whitespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django template tags allow you to have positional and named parameters, so, if you have a space, it will assume that  pk Is the first argument, = the seccond and so on.

So, if you you are passing named parameters, you have to use = without spaces, and if you are using positional parameters, you don't use = and separate them just by a space.

Answer (score 3):

Because django templates are text processed and this is the syntax, you could try the same thing in `bash`, this is off-topic, but it is processed the same way that statements are sensitive to whitespace.

valid in **bash**

```
declare TEST=SOMETHING # is valid
```

invalid in **bash**

```
declare TEST = SOMETHING # is invalid
```

(same as in django template language)

If your question was `Why this is sensitive to whitespace?` than the answer is `Because of syntax.` Some languages are case sensitive some are case insensitive, in some you must prefix every variable with dollar ($). Thats only the syntax matter. Everything is processed and if you want your pc to understand what is happening, than it must be formally expressed with correct syntax.

There are Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#syntax